# DB2 driver filename issue with Server configuration tool

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-installation

After installing a DB2 + WAS Liberty profile and the Mobile First server, we are trying to follow the [Installing MobileFirst Server administration with the  Server Configuration Tool](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_wlconsole_config_tool.html?lang=en) steps.

At step 6, we're attempting to connect to a DB2 (v10.5) running on localhost:50000.  After entering the hostname/port values - the message displayed in the panel is: "Invalid driver jar file name."

screenshot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAoAx.png

DB2 V10.5
IBM MobileFirst Platform Server Configuration Tool 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630
IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core - v8.5.5.7
IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition v7.0 for Libery 7.0.9.10

db2jcc4.jar was referenced during installation of the MobileFirst server components. Confirmed db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar exist in the WAS Liberty server profile

Anybody run into this?
Suspecting:

1. The Server Configuration tool isn't picking up the correct db2 jdbc jar file name .. bug?
2. The db2 driver jar name is misconfigured in a config file somewhere

Any pointers?

Comment: The link is missing to the steps you have followed. Also, could you add screen shots of the screen where you have setup the driver and license files? are there any white spaces in the path?

Comment: I believe the path to the DB2 drivers was requested during the MobileFirst Platform installation done via the Installation manager.  Unfortunately do not have the screen shots from that process.
To answer your question: no white spaces in the path that I can see. 
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/java/
Is there a Server Configuration Tool configuration file I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-enter the DB2 JDBC driver directory in the Server Configuration tool. Scroll down on the scren of the 'Database Settings' panel to have the text field to enter the directory.

Comment: Thanks!
Maximized the window .. and voila! the "Database Settings" panel now shows the text field where you can enter the db2 jar file path ..

I should remember to pay attention to scroll bars in the future :-(